# Question about unicode assignments in python

Tags: python, unicode

I have been learning Python for about a year. I need to understand using unicode glyphs. In particular, this set: https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U11D60.pdf

I tried this and when I tried to print it, (O didn't get the expected glyph:

```py
a = '\u11D72'
print(a)
```

I'm using VSCode on a Mac. What am I missing? I want to use these glyphs for an encryption program project using a translate table.

Something like this:

```py
mystr = 'String to be translated'
trans_dict = {'A':'\u11D72', 'B':'\u11D73', 'C':'\u11D74', ...}
mytable = mystr.maketrans(trans_dict)
mystr_translated = mystr.translate(mytable)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a `\U` + 8-hexadecimal code instead of `\u` + 4-hexadecimal code when the code point is more than four digits.  You'll also need an appropriate font so it may or may not show up with the correct glyph on your system.

```py
import unicodedata as ud

mytable = mystr.maketrans('ABC', '\U00011D72\U00011D73\U00011D74')
mystr_translated = 'ABC'.translate(mytable)
for c in mystr_translated:
    print(c, ud.name(c))
```

Output:

```
 GUNJALA GONDI LETTER KHA
 GUNJALA GONDI LETTER TA
 GUNJALA GONDI LETTER THA
```

See [Unicode HOWTO: Unicode Literals in Python Source Code](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code)